# Parallelizing pandas dataframe row iteration using multiprocessing instead of multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I am iterating over each row of a dataframe and I would like to know if there is a way I could use python's `multiprocessing` instead of threads to parallelize the iteration and speed up the process?

I'm using `thread` as follows:

```
def whole(row):

        final_wt = []
        final_val=[]
        wt = row[2] + 0.6*row[4] + 0.6*row[6] + 0.3*row[8]
        final_wt.append(wt)
        if row[1] == 'High':
            if row[3] == 'Low' and row[5] == 'Low' and row[7] == 'Low':
                final_val.append('Mod')
            else:
                final_val.append('High')
        elif row[1] == 'Mod':
            if row[3] == 'High' and row[5] == 'High':
                final_val.append('High')
            else:
                final_val.append('Mod')
        elif row[1] == 'Low':
            if row[3] == 'High' and row[5] == 'High':
                final_val.append('Mod')
            else:
                final_val.append('Low')

    return final_val, final_wt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        t = Thread(target=whole, args=(row,))
        t.start()
```

In the end, I would like to get `final_val` and `final_wt` lists containing values for the entire data frame. How do I use `from multiprocessing import Pool` for this??

UPDATE:

Sample df below (actual one is 600,000 rows long):

```
df = 

ID   | 1    | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   |
ABC1 | High | 1.0 | Low | 0.8 | Mod | 0.7 | Low | 1.0 |
CDV2 | High | 1.0 | Low | 0.8 | Mod | 0.7 | Low | 1.0 |
```

Comment: Oh boy, this is not the way to approach this issue. You should definitely drop threading for a start, but don't start multiprocessing. Look into "vectorization"; your aim is to get rid of the `for` loops if at all possible.

Comment: Can you please edit in some representative data from your dataframe for people to work with?

Comment: @roganjosh Added the sample df in the question

Comment: Have you sorted this issue?